# Can we install KVM without any Operating System installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm

I know I am asking some silly question. we recently purchased a HP Server. Now I first installed Ubuntu server Operating system and then installed KVM for visualization.

But according to my boss, first KVM supposed to be installed and then Ubuntu or any other OS as visualization machine.

My question is can we install KVM as stand alone without any operating system installed on the server like ubuntu, linux ? Or first we need to install the OS and then KVM to create VM as I did.

Anyone please help and advice.

Regards,
- Manoj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need to have an operating system to install KVM, because it is part of the Linux kernel itself.

The problem is you normally get a kernel with a linux distribution; so people assume to use KVM you need to first install ____ (insert your favorite distribution).

In fact, all you need to use KVM is a bootable USB stick with a KVM enabled kernel. You don't need an operating system on the host at all.  You can do this yourself, or use something like [proxmox](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Main_Page) which is a bootable image that includes KVM and a GUI.

Comment: Hi Burhan, Thank you for your answer. Highly appreciated if you please provide me some link as how to do this myself without using any tools like proxmox you mentioned ? How to create the bootable disc of KVM ? I googled a lot but didn't find any useful information as how to install KVM as standaline hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel acts as the virtualization engine - there is no stand-alone hypervisor.